# RabbitMQ .Net acknowledge multiple non-consecutive messages?

Tags: c#, .net, rabbitmq

Is there a way to ack/reject multiple messages that are not necessarily in order. May be by supplying a list of delivery tags to acknowledge? For example, there are 4 messages `1, 2, 3, 4` and I process 1 and 3 and acknowledge those at once and do some different processing on 2 and 4 and ack them afterwards?

My scenario is that I have 10's of messages that I fetch in a batch. I need to filter them based on `IBasicProperties.Type` field and decide which ones get processed first. If the processing on all types of messages is successful, then I can use BasicAck(messages.Last().DeliverTag, true), but in case one type of messages fail, I don't want to ack each message one by one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can acknowledge [multiple consecutive messages](https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html#consumer-acks-multiple-parameter). In your case, if you have messages 1 - 10 and processing on 1 - 5 is successful, then 7, then 9, you should multiple-ack using message 5's delivery tag, then individually ack 7 and 9.